# Scrapy - Crawl urls sequentially after a condition is met

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a spider that starts with four different `start_urls`, and then goes on crawling certain links inside. All of them have **the same domain and structure**, the only thing that changes is a query parameter between them. I use two rules: one for opening and parsing each link and one for following through with pagination.

My problem is: I don't want to crawl ALL links due to the extensive amount generated by pagination, so I need to check each link crawled for a condition (a publication year), and as soon as that year is different than the year I want, the spider should ignore the crawling of all remaining links belonging to that start_url, and then move on to the links generated by the second `start_url`. How can I go about doing this? here is the code for my spider:

```
class articleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'article'
    allowed_domains = ['website.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.website.com/search/?category=value1',
        'https://www.website.com/search/?category=value2',
        'https://www.website.com/search/?category=value3',
        'https://www.website.com/search/?category=value4',
        ]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='results-post']/article/a"
                ), 
            callback='parse_item', 
            follow=True,
           ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths="//section[@class='results-navi'][1]/div/div[@class='prevpageNav left']"
                )
            )
        )
    
    def parse_item(self, response):
        name = response.url.strip('/').split('/')[-1]
        date = response.xpath("//section/p/time/@datetime").get()[:4]
        if date == '2020':
            with open(f'./src/data/{name}.html', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.text.encode('utf8'))
                return
```

Thankss in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of an easy way to achieve this, but maybe the below (untested) code can help to get you started.
The logic is as follows:

- Overwrite start_requests to only begin with the first start-url only
- Pass the other start-urls in the meta
- In the parse method, grab the item-urls and the next-page url
- Go through the item-urls. While you're getting year 2020, it goes through the item_urls (and to the next-page url if you run out of item-urls). If you encounter a different year, you go to the next start_url.

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request


class articleSpider(Spider):
    name = 'article'
    allowed_domains = ['website.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.website.com/search/?category=value1',
        'https://www.website.com/search/?category=value2',
        'https://www.website.com/search/?category=value3',
        'https://www.website.com/search/?category=value4',
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = self.start_urls
        start_url = start_urls.pop()
        meta = {'start_urls': start_urls}
        yield Request(start_url, callback=self.parse, meta=meta)

    def parse(self, response):
        start_urls = response.meta['start_urls']
        # get item-urls
        item_urls = response.xpath(
            '//div[@class="results-post"]/article/a'
        ).extract()

        # get next page-url
        next_page = response.xpath(
            '//section[@class="results-navi"][1]/div/div[@class="prevpageNav left"]'
        ).extract_first()

        # pass the item-urls and next page in the meta
        item_url = item_urls.pop()
        meta = {
            'next_page': next_page,
            'item_urls': item_urls,
            'start_urls': start_urls
        }
        yield Request(item_url, self.parse_item, meta=meta)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item_urls = response.meta['item_urls']
        next_page = response.meta['next_page']
        start_urls = response.meta['start_urls']

        name = response.url.strip('/').split('/')[-1]
        date = response.xpath("//section/p/time/@datetime").get()[:4]
        if date == '2020':
            with open(f'./src/data/{name}.html', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.text.encode('utf8'))
            try:
                item_url = item_urls.pop()
            except IndexError:
                # all items are done - we go to next page
                if next_page:
                    meta = {'start_urls': start_urls}
                    yield Request(next_page, self.parse, meta=meta)
                else:
                    # no pages left, go to next start_url
                    try:
                        start_url = start_urls.pop()
                    except IndexError:
                        # nothing left to do
                        return
                    else:
                        meta = {'start_urls': start_urls}
                        yield Request(start_url, self.parse, meta=meta)
            else:
                # still items left to process
                meta = {
                    'next_page': next_page,
                    'item_urls': item_urls
                }
                yield Request(item_url, self.parse_item, meta=meta)

        else:
            # go to next start_url
            try:
                start_url = start_urls.pop()
            except IndexError:
                # nothing left to do
                return
            else:
                meta = {'start_urls': start_urls}
                yield Request(start_url, self.parse, meta=meta)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was helpful. Another working solution that I tried was adding a process_request method for each rule, tagging EACH REQUEST with the category belonging to the parent URL (value1, value2, etc.). when I stopped getting the year 2020,  I added the category tag to a "blacklist", and set the downloader middleware so that all the remaining requests with blacklisted categories would not be processed. The downside is that it will not be fully sequential, as each category site is being crawled independently from each other.